# How to Run a Process Before .class Files are Generated

Tags: java, compilation

I have almost identical code for Create/Update/Delete APIs that I am trying to replace with a Template model.

So I defined the Controller code in a text Template and then on Application startup I am trying to copy the Template into my project directory and replace the variables with real values to generate the APIs with the respective class names.

Then when I need to make a change I can change my Template and not every API to reduce overall code maintenance. The copy functionality is working, but it's happening after the .class files are generated. Meaning the code my application is actually using is always one version behind the current version.

In order for me to get the correct version running I need to restart the application once again without changing the Templates. That way the current version and previous version would be identical and it seems to be working properly.

However this isn't very convenient from a Production perspective. I tried using javax.tools.* to compile the code, but because I am using many dependencies inside my application it's failing unless I can compile my project together (including the files that need to be generated).

```
src\main\java\com\project\dao\model\User.java:3: error: package com.vividsolutions.jts.geom does not exist
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
                                  ^
src\main\java\com\project\dao\model\User.java:5: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.*;
```

Is it possible to:

1. Create the files before the .class files are generated so that the project can be compiled together. This was if the Template has errors or invalid variables were supplied a compilation error will be thrown.
2. Automate the Application Restart before it becomes fully available. This way the code will start and generate the files from the Template(s). Then it will shutdown. Then it will restart again automatically and recognize the newly generated files so the project can be compiled together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by splitting your dependencies in two. Or put another way, your template generator should not depend on the classes it generates.

That means you should not import anywhere, in your template generator code, the classes generated by the template.

Once you have your classes compiled, use `Class.forName("path.to.my.generated.class.Getter");` to instantiate your generated classes.

The rule of thumb here is: for any class that gets loaded, all its declared imports
 get loaded first. To avoid loading a dependency that way, use `Class.forName()`, which loads the class at the time of the call.

Note: all exception/error handling left out.

```
class MyCodeGenerator {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        generateCode();
        Class getterClass = Class.forName("path.to.my.generated.class.Getter");
        Object getter = getterClass.newInstance();
        Method initMethod = getterClass.getMethod("init");
        initMethod.invoke(getter);
    }
}

class Getter {
    public void init() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow, but the template generation code doesn't depend on the classes it's creating. I'm using Jtwig and can populate the files properly. The problem is within the template i am specifying Import statements for the dependencies the generated java class will use and those are what is causing the problem with the javax Compiler. I read that JShell (Java 9) may be able to do what I need, but I can't upgrade yet.

Comment: Oh, so you just generate source code. I thought you were also able to generate compiled code. My bad, although you might still want to have a look at it: see javax.tools package and more specifically ToolProvider..getSystemJavaCompiler() (These come with the JDK, not the JRE)